# In which class the MessageId , Delivery Count , ScheduledEnqueueTime, Deadletter method and abandon Method () availabe in V4 function app

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

In which class the MessageId, Delivery Count, ScheduledEnqueueTime,  Deadletter method and abandon method available in service bus? I am using Azure v4 Function app and servicebus received message class for my service bus trigger function app but in service bus ne deadletter and abandon method supports.

Need class file for this issue

Answer (score 1):

You're using Functions Isolated Worker SDK. It doesn't support message settlement **yet**. No need to file a new issue. Monitor [Service Bus message settlement scenarios milestone](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/milestone/62) to get the updates on the progress.